# MySQL: Status of SELECT INTO OUTFILE from JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

What is the best way to know programatically, using JDBC, whether a `SELECT INTO OUFILE` command has executed successfully?

The `execute` method on the `Statement` interface will always return false in this case because, [as the documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)):

> **Returns:**
> true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

Comment: The usual indication is whether or not a `SQLException` is thrown. Why do you think that would be different here?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel.  I agree with your observation that catching the `SQLException` is the correct approach.